# Clustering evaluation and adjusted rand index

Tags: clustering, panel-data

How can we evaluate clustering methods in a efficient way? Imagine I generate artificial data and the true clusters are something like "A,A,A,A,..,A,B,B,B,..,B". After I applied some clustering method and I get the results, the method can actually guess all clusters but name it "B,B,B,B...,B,A,A,A,..,A" instead. In that case, with the confusion matrix the method will have 0% accuracy while in fact, it guessed them right but labeled them in a wrong way. Does the adjusted rand index have this in account? Also, if the clustering method finds 3 clusters instead of 2 and has something like "A,B,A,C,A..,etc" does the adjusted rand index take that in account ?

(In my case, I'm using longitudinal data and I'm generating artificial data with the function gald of kml package)

Comment: If the clustering labels are arbitrary, then in your first example the clustering seems to be perfect. The Rand Index is not supposed to look at the culster labels, but instead whether data pairs in the same or different classes have been put in the same or different clusters

Comment: @Henry Yes, they are arbitrary. I did adjusted rand index and correct classification rate (with confusion matrix) with that example and i got adjusted rand index = 1 , while cRate =0. That means that the adjusted rand index kinda worked.

Comment: @Henry I'm using adjustedRandIndex from mclust package. The function basicaly compares two character vectors. If the letters are the same it means they belong to the same cluster